# What is this tool? Chisel-decorative-beating

Tags: hand-tools

Sharpened like a chisel. Marked with imperial size (means that it is old here in Sweden). Has a back end that has taken quite some beating.
I have an idea it is for decorative purpose but why have size for that?

[image: A tool in the hand is better than 10 in the workshop.]

Comment: Stone-working tool? Without a handle it seems less likely to be for woodworking, although the handle could have been lost (shaft broke) and that user or subsequent users continued to use it in its shortened form. There is lots of precedent for this among woodworkers LOL

Comment: I've never seen one exactly like this one, but it looks to me like a leather punch, like might be used to make tassle-ends on fancy loafers. These would typically be driven through leather by a hammer (although usually a rawhide mallet not hard enough to mushroom the head). The leather would be backed by a hard-rubber mat to protect the bench. I can't tell from the picture, but the edges look sharpened at an acute angle, like wouldn't hold up in stone. But there are similar chisels used to contour soft stone, so that could be it. Those *are* hit with a metal hammer I think.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a pinking iron. It is a struck punch type of tool used for decorative shaping of leather and cloth.

The reasons for the sizes are similar for that of any instrument or tool. Repeatability, precision, and aesthetic choice regarding ratios and proportions of specific projects to name a few. They are marked for rapid identification so that a craftsperson may easily and swiftly select the right tool for the job.

Comment: Here's [an example](https://brucejohnsonleather.com/files/gallery/watermark/3898/6481__unmarked_1-to_inch_pinking_punch__50.JPG).